# Привязать данные к progressbar`у в listBox`е

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ReadAndVerify.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReadAndVerify"
        xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Background="#20201f" Foreground="White">
    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <ProgressBar Value="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="20"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Foreground="White" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <ListBox Name="lstCars" Margin="5" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}">
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

c#:

```
private List<Project> _projects = Project.GetProjects();
public MainWindow()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    lstCars.ItemsSource = _projects;
}
```

Project.cs:

```
[Serializable]
public class Project
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    private static string pathToFile = @"..\..\Xml\Project.xml";

    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("StartDate")]
    public DateTime StartDateForProject { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("FinishDate")]
    public DateTime FinishDateForProject { get; set; }

    public Project() { }

    public Project(string title,DateTime startDate, DateTime finishDate)
    {
        Title = title;
        StartDateForProject = startDate;
        FinishDateForProject = finishDate;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "20";
    }
}
```

> Если вместо `{Binding}` написать 20 - то все хорошо. А так привязываться не хочет? Почему - не пойму. Помогите плиз.

Comment: Какие данные привязать то? Он что показывать должен?

Comment: @tym32167 `Value`. Просто когда я вместо биндинг пишу в xaml коде значение `Value`, то все хорошо отображается. Так вот, как мне это `Value` вытянуть с объекта.

Comment: куда вы привязаться хотите я понял, я спрашивал что вы к этому Value привязывать собрались? Вот вы хотите, например, показать на прогресс баре 50% - это что у вас в модели должно такое быть, чтобы в результате получить 50? Как вы эти 50 посчитаете?

Comment: @tym32167 разница 2х дат в днях

Comment: ну так а как вы пробовали 2 даты прибиндить к одному числу? Тут либо надо свойство добавлять во вьюмодель с разностью, либо конвертер писать

Comment: ну, и, например, вот у вас есть 2 даты. Разница между ними, например, 10 дней. У вас сколько должен прогресс бар показывать? Это 10%? или 90% или 42%?

Comment: @tim32167 допустим у меня есть публичная переменная double в классе Progect. Как мне ее прибиндить к Value прогресс бара? Интересует сие только, а как посчитать это число я думаю сам разберусь.

Comment: @tym32167 если это нужно - привязываемое число - это процент дня на разностном интервале двух дат ( например интервал равен десяти дням, если текущий день равен 2му, то прогресс бара показывает 20%)

Comment: Нет такого понятия как публичная переменная. Вы можете прибиндить публичное поле с геттером и сеттером, делается это точно также, как вы биндите другие поля в своем примере. Если вы хотите ещё и обновлять свойство и чтобы прогресс бар реагировал на это, вам надо реализовать интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged. Как это делать вы можете узнать из соседнего вопроса, например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889805/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-progressbar-%D0%B2-wpf) есть прямо готовый пример

Comment: @tym32167 хорошо, буду пробовать, спасибо